# Package requirements in a new, clean venv project (Python 3 /IntelliJ IDEA) - Why are there any?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, virtualenv, project-setup

After creating a new Python project in IntelliJ:

[image: Choosing venv and basic python3.6 interepreter, no inheriting of packages]

There shouldn't be any requirements/additional packages.

I check this:

[image]

So, to recap: I create a *new* project, select VENV, choose a new environment, and do not want inherit any requirements.

When I create an empty Python file, I get this:

[image]

Where is this coming from? I don't see any requirements file, etc. But it must be somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*VirtualEnv* copies *PIP* and *SetupTools*, in case you want to install new packages in the virtual environment (which is the main reason for *VirtualEnv*'s existence).

- You can suppres them by passing *--no-pip*, *--no-setuptools* to *VirtualEnv*'s command line ([[PyPA.VirtualEnv]: virtualenv Command](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/#virtualenv-command))
- *PyCharm* (I assume it's the same for *Idea*) on the other hand, doesn't seem to expose those options in its *GUI*, only *--system-site-packages* ([[JetBrains]: Configuring Virtualenv Environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/creating-virtual-environment.html#Creating_Virtual_Environment.xml))

So, the only way that I see (if you don't want them), is to create the new virtual environment from command line, and then "import" it in *PyCharm*.

Regarding the 2<sup>nd</sup> dilemma, it (might not be your case, but) sounds like an *PyCharm* caching problem. In [[JetBrains.IntelliJ-Support]: Package requirements not satisfied (though they are)](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001522219-Package-requirements-not-satisfied-though-they-are-), *Sergey Karpov* states:

> Please try to remove this interpreter from IDE, then do **File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.. | Invalidate and Restart** and add the interpreter again.

---

#### Edit #0

I made a confusion: I talked about *VirtualEnv*, when in fact it's [[Python 3.Docs]: venv - Creation of virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) that' being used. Nevertheless, this doesn't change much, the problem still persists, but only the *--without-pip* options is present.

Regarding the other problem, as I specified in a comment, I tried reproducing the behavior on my laptop, but I couldn't.

Comment: 2nd dilemma wasnt due to this, I already tried it. and the first one is very..unsatisfying. but if that is the case and there aren't any other responses, ill take this as best answer - thank you

Comment: Regarding the 1st problem this is how things are at the current point, there's nothing you can do (maybe submit an enhancement request to add those options in the *GUI*). Now regarding the 2nd one: the problem didn;t go away after invalidating caches. Is there something that doesn't work? Are you able to run your file (might want to add a dummy *print* to see some output in the console). Also are you able to debug it?

Comment: I followed your steps, but I couldn't reproduce the behavior. Probably there's something messed up in your environment. Removing the *.idea* dir and try again.

Comment: im on a different project at work atm, so ill come back to this when I find the time..thank you for your input!

Comment: You're welcome!. Did you try deleting the dir (and thus recreating the project)?